# auth_tkt for nginx?

Tags: authentication, module, nginx

I'm looking for a [mod_auth_tkt](http://www.openfusion.com.au/labs/mod_auth_tkt/) for **Nginx**? I have multiple applications using auth_tkt compatible cookies and would like to have SSO. I don't want to use apache2 mod_auth_tkt, since I have nginx already running. Is there a auth_tkt compatible module for nginx?

Comment: Seems like nginx 1.3.8 will ship with https://mdounin.ru/hg/ngx_http_auth_request_module/ making this possible

Answer (score 0):

I came across this challenge today (multi-domain SSO using Nginx), so I suppose an answer is better late than never.

I was coming from having used auth_tkt with Apache2.

Ultimately I ended up with an implementation of [Pubcookie](http://www.pubcookie.org/), for which somebody wrote and documented an [Nginx module](http://www.vitki.net/book/page/pubcookie-module-nginx).

The setup is very similar:

1. A CGI script intercepts the request and performs login procedure for the user using whatever mechanism is configured
2. Upon successful authentication:

   a. A cookie is set on the `enterprise_domain`

   b. User is redirected to the originally requested resources

Some warning though, I had to hack the source a fair bit for pubcookie and the nginx module to get it to work with non-SSL sites - it seems to have been written with SSL as a fixed assumption.

Comment: Pubcookie is not compatible with auth_tkt, sadly. I need to use auth_tkt, since all the applications support that.

Comment: @iElectric can you elaborate why Pubcookie wouldn't work? I've found it to be completely agnostic to the underlying application, as mod_tkt was.